# How to remove everything in a directory except one file in a subdirectory?

Tags: bash

I need to delete everything in directory `d1`, except the file `d1/d2/f1.txt`. How can I do that in bash?

Comment: Assuming you are in the same directory as d1, you can use the following command:
rm -rf d1/* d1/d2/* !d1/d2/f1.txt

Comment: @SimonSultana This seems to remove d1/d2/f1.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. It will delete everything, but the directories in path of `f1.txt` and of course the file itself.

```
find d1/ ! -iregex '\(d1/\|d1/d2\|d1/d2/f1.txt\)' -delete
```

**However**, I would strongly suggest against using `-delete` as it is permanent and mistyping a character could be disastorous...

You should try something like this instead, putting files and directories in trash folder first just in case you delete a file you don't want to delete you can recover it.

```
mkdir -p ~/.Trash
find d1/ ! -iregex '\(d1/\|d1/d2\|d1/d2/f1.txt\)' -exec mv {} ~/.Trash \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the contents to delete except for (`!`) specific file:

```
find d1/ -type f ! -name 'd1/d2/f1.txt' -delete
```

Comment: Thanks. But this seems to keep all the directories in d1

Comment: Add the `-depth` option to `find` to delete the directories.